# phpMyAdmin - #1044 - Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I am trying to set up my WordPress project, and I am using WampServer. In phpMyAdmin, I simply tried to create a new database, but I got this error :  #1044 - Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'wp'. I never had this problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WAMPServer when you run `phpMyAdmin` you are shown a login screen.

By default :

The Username = root

And the Password is not set so you should not enter a password in the Password field.

Then press the `Go` button to login.

This will log you in as the `root` SuperUser, who can do anything on a MySQL Server.

> If you leave the Username blank, like it appears you did, you are logged in as an annonymous user with no rights to do anything much at all.

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't pay attention and for username I wrote username instead of root. Now it works, thanks for everyone again

Answer (score 0):

Login to the web console for phpMyAdmin and navigate to the wp database

Click on the SQL tab and paste this code:

> grant all privileges on wp.* to user@localhost identified by 'PASSWORD';
>   flush privileges;
>   \q

Change the user's credentials to match your config, then
Click Ok and it should work!

You can [read more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) about GRANT's syntax at MySQL's site.

Hope it helps!

Comment: WAMPServer ... the W=Windows

Comment: Not if OP is trying to login using a blank Username! As it appears they are

Comment: Try root credentials to login as you set whilest installing